# objective-c looking for algorithm

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm

In my application I need to determine what the plates a user can load on their barbell to achieve the desired weight.

For example, the user might specify they are using a 45LB bar and have 45,35,25,10,5,2.5 pound plates to use. For a weight like 115, this is an easy problem to solve as the result neatly matches a common plate. 115 - 45 / 2 = 35.

So the objective here is to find the largest to smallest plate(s) (from a selection) the user needs to achieve the weight.

My starter method looks like this...

```
 -(void)imperialNonOlympic:(float)barbellWeight workingWeight:(float)workingWeight {
     float realWeight = (workingWeight - barbellWeight);
     float perSide = realWeight / 2;

     .... // lots of inefficient mod and division ....
 }
```

My thought process is to determine first what the weight per side would be. Total weight - weight of the barbell / 2. Then determine what the largest to smallest plate needed would be (and the number of each, e.g. 325 would be 45 * 3 + 5 or 45,45,45,5.

Messing around with fmodf and a couple of other ideas it occurred to me that there might be an algorithm that solves this problem. I was looking into BFS, and admit that it is above my head but still willing to give it a shot.

Appreciate any tips on where to look in algorithms or code examples.

Comment: You don't need an algorithm as you have one already.  It is easy to do, just go with the largest weight until the remaining is less than that, and continue to go down and finish off with the 5 point weights.

Comment: @JamesBlack it's will not work.Its a min coin problem (solved using DP). you cant follow the procedure you said, for example, let say the total weight required = 123, and the weights present are 50,41,1. 
According to your solution, you will have 123 = 50*2+23*1,(total 25 items), but 123 = 41*3, 3 is the best solution.You have to use Dynamic programming to get it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247662/the-minimum-number-of-coins-the-sum-of-which-is-s

Comment: Thanek, santhu. That describes the problem well and your link gives me something to start solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is called [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). You will find a lot solution for this problem. There are some variant of this problem. It is basically a Dynamic Programming (DP) problem.

One of the common approach is that, you start taking the largest weight (But less than your desired weight) and then take the largest of the remaining weight. It easy. I am adding some more links ( [Link 1](http://www.es.ele.tue.nl/education/5MC10/Solutions/knapsack.pdf), [Link 2](http://www.programminglogic.com/knapsack-problem-dynamic-programming-algorithm/), [Link 3](http://cse.unl.edu/~goddard/Courses/CSCE310J/Lectures/Lecture8-DynamicProgramming.pdf) ) so that it becomes clear. But some problems may be hard to understand, skip them and try to focus on basic knapsack problem. Good luck.. :)

Let me know if that helps.. :)

Comment: Very helpful, really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks. Your question reminds me of old days. Once I spent a lot of time solving algorithmic problems for ACM ICPC. Now a full time developer.. :P
Real fun was solving problems.. :)