# Find the coins required which sum to S and we can use coin only one time

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

Given a list of N coins, their values (V1, V2, ... , VN), and the total sum S. Find the coins the sum of which is S. **We can use one coin only one time.**

I was recently studying the very same problem [here](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247662/the-minimum-number-of-coins-the-sum-of-which-is-s?rq=1), but there we can use the coins any number of times.

How to solve it?

Comment: This problem is called the [Subset sum problem - from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). You can find your problem in the second paragraph of the article: "An equivalent problem is this: given a set of integers and an integer s, does any non-empty subset sum to s?"

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I think you can post it as an answer.